# Suitable font for work with Moodle

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, moodle

I do quizzes in Moodle and sometimes the questions have to include an illustration. I have decided to create these images in LaTeX and have thought about everything except which font to use so that the images blend in as well as possible with the rest of the text.

The font should be sans serif for both text and math, and the Greek uppercase letters in math should be italic by default (as required by ISO 80000). Can you suggest a suitable font?

I do not know exactly what font Moodle uses, but I found this specification:

```
% font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
```

PS: I have already tried various options. I almost made it with `opensans`, but I wasn't able to make uppercase Greek italic.

```
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage[italic,LGRgreek]{mathastext}
```

Comment: The font of the webpage will probably depend on what the users have available, whatever you pick, it won't blend in for everybody.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz IMHO vast majority of users will see sans serif font as a default font on the webpage.  So finding a most generic sans serif with the conditions in OP will probably be good enough.

Comment: @Pygmalion `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, ...` essentially means that the creators of the website chose to use the font of the operating system. So, the font will differ depending on which device you use. As far as I know, none of these fonts support math, however. So, maybe just choose a sans-serif font that supports math, such as Noto? Noto is freely available and has a plain style which should blend in well enough.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing "Best font" to "Suitable font" in the title of your query. Assessing which font is "best" is every bit as subjective as "What's the best icecream" or "where is the world's most beautiful beach"?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you for your suggestions.  However, `noto` has no documentation and I tried `\usepackage{noto-sans}` and `\usepackage[sf]{noto}` and still got serifs.